# SQL QUERY CLAUS WHERE

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have this where clause

```
WHERE        (ACCDAT_0 >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000')and STA_0='3'
and
(NUM_0 LIKE '%FTC%') OR (NUM_0 LIKE '%NCC%') OR (NUM_0 LIKE '%DCF%')
```

The point is that if `STA_0='1'` is appearing in the query because its like NCC it possible to appear all NCC except the ones where the flag is 1?

Comment: Sorry, could you please make this more clear? Which query are you executing, which is the current result and which is the desired result? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please add some sample data, what you expect to happen and why...  I think this will help clarify your issue.  Unfortunately, I don't completely understand your issue yet.  Off the bat, I'd say you are dealing with precedent constraints by not enclosing your OR statements, but that's purely a guess

Comment: What do you mean by `NCC` ?

Comment: "The point is that if STA_0='1' is appearing in the query"   Something appearing in the query is because you wrote it there.   When you mean that this is in the results; That's because of the `... OR (NUM_0 LIKE '%NCC%') OR (NUM_0 LIKE '%DCF%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a comment, but it's too large to fit in the comment space...  elaboration on my comment above.

"OR" is a low precedence operator, meaning it is evaluated after all "AND."  What this means is your query is doing this:

```
WHERE
 (ACCDAT_0 >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' and
  STA_0='3' and
  NUM_0 LIKE '%FTC%') OR NUM_0 LIKE '%NCC%' OR NUM_0 LIKE '%DCF%'
```

Meaning if NUM_0 is like NCC or DCF, then the first two criteria are ignored.  That may not be what you meant, but that's what you said.

You might have meant this:

```
WHERE
  ACCDAT_0 >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' and
  STA_0='3' and
 (NUM_0 LIKE '%FTC%' OR NUM_0 LIKE '%NCC%' OR NUM_0 LIKE '%DCF%')
```

And the larger lesson is...  if you mix AND and OR, be sure to use parentheses so it does exactly what you mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help